# What to use instead of FileReader for Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, filereader

(Am new to web programming, so apologies for any lack of rudimentary knowledge.)

My page allows a user to select a file that is then read clientside & displayed in a textbox on the page.  The easiest way I found to do this was to use a FileReader object, which works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

This doesn't work in Safari (yet), so what should I do instead?

```
//When the eventlistener detects a change in the input file...
var file = evt.target.files[0]
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e){document.getElementById('data').value = e.target.result};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

Relevant Notes:

- I'm working with Safari for windows
- Right now the page is local as is the file to read.  Chrome had issues with this until I used the flag --allow-file-access-from-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, the only answer I can come up with will hog some extra bandwidth.

Firstly, use something like `if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined"` or [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to follow your normal flow for the browsers that DO support FileReader. Otherwise, POST the file via AJAX to some server-side script that echoes back the contents.

So for compliant browsers, you get to save yourself some bandwidth and for non-compliant browsers you have to take one for the team.

Comment: Maybe this would satisfy your need though: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

Comment: Thanks!  It felt silly, but I just didn't know what the alternative possibilities were (guess that happens when you're still new to everything!)

Comment: I really liked your answer, seems like a responsive way of handle this situations. Thank you.

Comment: @Quickredfox bro I have the same problem, I have understood the first part and it works perfect,  But the ajax part is confusing me  Do i need to send the whole input file in ajax? please explain in detail the following is my code



function showimagepreview(input)
 {
if(input.files && input.files[0])
{
if (window.FileReader){
 var fr=new FileReader();
     fr.onload=function(e)
    {
     $("#image").attr('src',e.target.result);
   $("#storedProfileImage").attr('value',e.target.result);
}
    fr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else{
     alert();
     console.log(input.files);
}} }

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use "A FileReader polyfill for Internet Explore and Safari using Flash"

See: https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader