# File API Not Working in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, safari, fileapi

I am testing three different browsers, chrome, firefox and safari.

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
{
       //check whether browser fully supports all File API 
}
```

It returns true for chrome and firefox.. but it does not return true for safari.

Does safari support File API?

Comment: think similar thread?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734150/what-to-use-instead-of-filereader-for-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/fileapi), yes it supports, but be careful about previous versions.

Comment: im using version 5.7,

Comment: Before version 6.0, it is partially supported, so some of its stuffs won't work. Check with different combinations in your `if` and see which one you can use.