# FileReader or URL not working in safari

Tags: jquery, safari-web-inspector

I am uploading image in my webpage. when i select image, images shows in a div before upload. it is working in all browser but not working in safari.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = fimageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

FileReader function is not working. 
in place of this i used.

```
var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

for get tempath of file but it is also not working. 
error is coming can not find variable URL.
Please help to solve this.

Comment: how does this involve PHP?

Comment: safari 5 on windows not support FileReader API

Comment: Thankyou. but i know. it is not working in safari 5

Comment: what can i use instead of FileReader() or URL to show the image in safari. please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on windows not support FileReader. you can get more information from here:

[What to use instead of FileReader for Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7962072/894111)

if you want to have fielReader, i think the best way is using flash when your client browser is Safari.

Comment: Safari on Windows doesn't exists since years ago. The link maybe is useful, but the comment is out of place :)

Comment: do you read the question? before try to proof you have knowledge please read the question.

Comment: the question is about FileReader API and not about when apple release last version of Safari for windows. Filereader API is common problem in Safari, and i taught it will be helpful.

Comment: and please tell me about URL

Comment: I tell you that is useful, but the comment "Safari on windows" sounds too old. Sorry if I disturb you.